# What is the jquery regex to match "-123x123" in this string "http://path/to/file/file-name-123x123.jpg"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

where file name could contain any digits before the "-123x123", numbers in the "-123x123" could be any numeric values.

Comment: Which ones have you tried???

Comment: `"http://path/to/file/file-name-123x123.jpg".match(/\-\d+x\d+/)[0]`?

Comment: You forgot to add you actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
-\d+x\d+(?=\.jpg)
```

`\d` means "digit"

`(?=....)` means "followed by"

A link: http://regular-expressions.info